# pygame does not detect joystick

Tags: python, pygame, joystick

I have a Logitech dual action controller that `pygame` doesn't seem to detect.
I tried something simple to start:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
pygame.joystick.init()
x = pygame.joystick.get_count()
print( x )
```

...which only returns `0` controllers connected.

If I try:

```
j = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
j.init()
```

I get:

> pygame.error: invalid joystick device number

I used `LibUSB` to verify that the device is indeed attached but I've no clue why `pygame` won't detect it.

Comment: Have you tried running as a user with higher privileges?

Comment: I'm already administrator. I should mention this is a winxp box with Python 3.3 and the latest pygame.

Comment: It's detecting now. I think it might have been a faulty port or a faulty usb extension cable I was using.